# accessing character values in data frame in R

Tags: r

I am using R and I have a data frame like this ( Lot of rows)

```
 DATE TICKER PERMNO PERMCO   BIDLO ASKHI    PRC CFACPR
1 20060901   ALOG  14198    173 55.8112 57.59 56.440      1
2 20060905   ALOG  14198    173 55.0101 56.48 55.650      1
3 20060906   ALOG  14198    173 55.0200 56.53 55.380      1
4 20060907   ALOG  14198    173 55.1200 57.05 56.360      1
5 20060908   ALOG  14198    173 55.3180 56.98 55.345      1
6 20060911   ALOG  14198    173 54.0000 56.23 56.190      1
```

I am trying to access the TICKER value of any of rows. 
Like this

```
> data[1,]$TICKER

[1] ALOG
150 Levels:  ACTG ACTL AEIS ALOG ALSC ALTR AMCC AMK AMSC ANAD ARMH ARMHY ARXX ASTSF ASYS ATMI ATML AVNX AXTI BELFA BELFB BRCM CAMD CATT CBMX CECE ... ZRAN
```

Why do I get the 150 Levels below the actual value. How do I just access the TICKER symbol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `stringsAsFactor=FALSE`, either as an option to `read.table()` or `read.csv()`, or as a global setting.  If you do, values will be strings.

```
R> data <- read.table(textConnection(" DATE TICKER PERMNO PERMCO   BIDLO ASKHI    PRC CFACPR
1 20060901   ALOG  14198    173 55.8112 57.59 56.440      1
2 20060905   ALOG  14198    173 55.0101 56.48 55.650      1
3 20060906   ALOG  14198    173 55.0200 56.53 55.380      1
4 20060907   ALOG  14198    173 55.1200 57.05 56.360      1
5 20060908   ALOG  14198    173 55.3180 56.98 55.345      1
6 20060911   ALOG  14198    173 54.0000 56.23 56.190      1"), header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
data <- read.table(textConnection(" DATE TICKER PERMNO PERMCO   BIDLO ASKHI    PRC CFACPR
+ 1 20060901   ALOG  14198    173 55.8112 57.59 56.440      1
+ 2 20060905   ALOG  14198    173 55.0101 56.48 55.650      1
+ 3 20060906   ALOG  14198    173 55.0200 56.53 55.380      1
+ 4 20060907   ALOG  14198    173 55.1200 57.05 56.360      1
+ 5 20060908   ALOG  14198    173 55.3180 56.98 55.345      1
+ 6 20060911   ALOG  14198    173 54.0000 56.23 56.190      1"), header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
R> data[1,"TICKER"]
[1] "ALOG"
R>
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason you're getting the levels below the outcome is because TICKER is being treated as a factor.  Dirk provides some advice for how you can prevent that from happening in the first place but you can convert from the factor to a character by using `as.character`

```
as.character(data[1, "TICKER"])
```

Alternatively if you want to change the entire column to a character vector instead of a factor you could do something like

```
data$TICKER <- as.character(data$TICKER)
```